# Sending traffic from multiple source IPs Scapy

Tags: python, linux, networking, scapy

I am trying to send some traffic via python using scapy (on Ubuntu). I am using a range of source IPs (10.0.0.32/29). Everything seems to be working (at least I see the traffic in wireshark and it reaches my firewall) but I am having a problem completing the TCP handshake using the IP addresses that aren't the main IP of the eth0 adapter. Does anyone know if this is possible to do:

Source:

```
 from scapy.all import *
 import random


 sp=random.randint(1024,65535)
 ip=IP(src="10.0.0.234/29",dst="www.google.com")
 SYN=TCP(sport=sp, dport=80,flags="S",seq=10)
 SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN)

 my_ack=SYNACK.seq+1
 ACK=TCP(sport=sp,dport=80,flags="A",seq=11,ack=my_ack)
 send(ip/ACK)
 payload="SEND TCP"

 PUSH=TCP(sport=sp,dport=80,flags="PA",seq=11,ack=my_ack)
 send(ip/PUSH/payload)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are behind a NAT/router, you should check it allows you to use the full range of IPs. If it is running DHCP protocol, your eth0 will typically recieve a unique IP adress that will be the only routed in your private network.

Furthermore, you must ensure your kernel knows what IPs are attributed to it, else it will drop response packets. If you want to use the full range of IP, you have two choices :

1. Create [virtual devices](http://www.bertera.it/index.php/2011/10/04/howto-configure-multiple-mac-address-over-a-single-ethernet-interface/) with virtual mac adresses, each requesting an IP through DHCP.
2. Configure your router so it statically routes the full IP table to your host, and [alias each IP](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Alias/commands.html) you intend to use

Once you have done that, there is no reason you wouldn't be able to syn/ack from your multiple source IPs. From distant server point of view, there wouldn't be any difference between what you are trying to do and several machines in a local network requesting a page at the same time.